# Why does PHPSpec fail to test thrown exceptions using ::shouldThrow()?

Tags: phpspec

I am trying to test whether a method throws an exception in PHPSpec.  Here is the method being tested; it is either running a Callable or a controller's action.  I am trying to test whether the exception at the end is being thrown.

```
function dispatch($target, $params=array()) 
{
    // call closure?
    if( is_callable( $target ) ) {
        call_user_func_array( $target, $params ); 
        return true;
    }   

    // call controller
    list($controllerClass, $actionMethod) = explode('@', $target);
    $controllerClass = $this->controllerNamespace . '\\' . $controllerClass;
    if (!class_exists($controllerClass)) {
        throw new \Exception('Controller not found: '.$controllerClass);
    }
}
```

Here is the PHPSpec test case:

```
function it_throws_an_exception_if_the_controller_class_isnt_callable()
{
   $this->shouldThrow('\Exception')->duringDispatch('Nonexistentclass@Nonexistentmethod', array());
}
```

This is consistent with the documentation on PHPSpec:
http://www.phpspec.net/en/latest/cookbook/matchers.html#throw-matcher

The problem is if I comment the throw new \Exception line, this test still passes.  It doesn't appear to test the method at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new exception class, throw it in `dispatch()` instead of `\Exception` and check in `phpspec` if that exception is thrown.

From the behaviour you described I suspect `dispatch()` throws an `\Exception` before reaching the `if (! class_exists())` statement (even that line could be the culprit if the autoloader throws an exception).

I pasted your function into a class of my project (it happened I was working with `phpspec` right now) and the spec worked flawless in both cases (when the exception is thrown and when the `throw \Exception` line was commented out).

Comment: Thanks axiac.  That was definitely it.  I also had the option of passing the Exception message (if I removed the class name from the message), but your advice of creating a new exception class is better.